# How to convert ipv4 address to ipv6 use AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking, ipv6

I've a problem with `IPV6`.

**Apple reject my app with error:**

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad and iPhone running iOS 10.0.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
>
> Specifically, your app stayed static at the launch screen and there was no further content loaded.
>
> We've attached screenshot(s) for your reference.

But my sever is not supporting `IPV6`. I use library `AFNetworking` to connect server. Please help me some solution? Thank you for any support!

Comment: you need to debug your app in a NAT64 Network.

Comment: Thanks you for supporting

Comment: Can you give me a link :" debug your app in a NAT64 Network". because i can enable ipv6 in my mac?

Comment: please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this error a month ago, then I updated `AFNetworking` to last version and Apple's `Reachability` class too, my problem solved, you can try this, I hope it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link:

[Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html)

This may be helpful:
[Transitioning to IPv6-only networks](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4971)

It covers the topic you described.