# My ios app got rejected due to ipv6 network issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipv6, reachability

My app got rejected with message from Apple as "Your app crashes on iPad running iOS 10.0.2 connected to an IPv6 network.” and also did not get anything from the crash log attached. Please reply whoever resolved this issue.

Actually I am getting server not found error whenever trying to access the api server from ipv6 only network. My api server only supports ipv4 network. Do I need to change anything in api server? Can anyone post any sample code to access api server using NSUrlConnection object that support the ipv6 only network?

Comment: just update the reachibility from apple and try

Comment: are you using `UIWebview` in your app ? UIWebView is deprecated. WKWebView is recommended by Apple.

Comment: how do i update reachability @Anbu Karthik

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `AFNetworking` library or Apple's `Reachability` class, updating your classes, than problem solved.

Comment: [Download sample code from here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: I wrote answer to another topic. [Your problem solution is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826837/how-to-convert-ipv4-address-to-ipv6-use-afnetworking/39827373#39827373)

Answer (score 0):

Don't get confused by that message. I got that too but the problem is not necessarily caused by the IPv6 Network. My feeling is they just write this always even if the error is something else. I had this with an app myself last week but the error was just a completely different reason. Maybe you just look into your code where the problem occurred. They probably wrote at which point in your app it crashed.

Comment: actually I am getting server is not reachable when try to login. After debugging found that whenever trying to access api server, It returns no server found. I think DNS is not resolved. But I am not finding any clue to resolve this issue.

Comment: but why does this lead to a crash? You should fix that too. No connectivity should not lead to crashes.

Answer (score 0):

App is now approved by the apple review team after increasing the target version to 9.2 previously it was 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of server environments have not started supporting IPV6 (Think Azure in some configurations). This causes the scenario where the api being used by the app are not useable. Do handle such scenarios in your code.

Apple's own reachability class and some other third party frameworks use low level apis/sockets for their own purpose. These are the problematic areas.

Most of the High level code using NSURLConnection is ok, but if you are using any third party libraries or older versions of AFNetworking, you'll need to check if they are using any sockets. If they are, then look for options/upgrades.

We faced the same issue recently, ended up with lots of fixes to server and third party libs in the app.